# Web API: How to sign in a user correctly?

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-web-api

When the user is logging in, I need to remember him, because only logged in users should be able to reach /api/prenews (for example). This is how I'm trying to do it. (The userName variable is a string, which stores the current username if the log in was successful.)

```
IList<Claim> claimCollection = new List<Claim>
{
       new Claim("username",userName)
 };

ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claimCollection);
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, claimsIdentity);
```

I implemented the PrenewsController.cs like this:

```
    public class PrenewsController : ApiController
    {
        /*
        ...
        */
        public IHttpActionResult GetPrenews()
        {
            string currentUser = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Type == "username").Value;
            if(currentUser!=null)//the user is logged in
            {/*...*/}
            else //the user is not logged in
            {/*...*/}
        }
    }
```

But `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Type == "username")` is always null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you store username in claims? There are better ways on getting the  username of the logged in user.

Comment: Because HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn needs a ClaimsIdentity[] second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get username from User.Identity property no need to add it to claims, also I guess your claim is null cause IsPersistent property is set to false in your example, try setting it to true and it should work.

**EDITED**

Try this:

```
var user = userManager.Find(userName, password);
var userIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("usename", "johndoe"));
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = persistCookie }, userIdentity)
```

this method definetely worked for me.. I hope it helps.

Comment: I set the IsPersistent property to true, but it's still null. I tried to get the username from the User.Identity.Name, but it was always an empty string, even if I logged in earlier. Should I change something around the HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn method for the User.Identity to work?

Comment: I think your signIn method is ok, are you using UserManager class in your project? creating claimsidentity with usermanager might help.